# Popover implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I want to make my popover control. Most of the problems like arrow orientation, popover positioning and etc I can solve myself. The one thing that I'm uncertain how to do in the best possible way is how to hide it when user clicks outside. Any link to a good example or implementation advises are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to bind `mousedown` handler to `document.body` and check if click was within popover.el.

```
   var popover = Ext.create('Your.Poopover', {/* ... */});

   popover.mon(Ext.getBody(), 'mousedown', function(e) {
     if (popover.isVisible() && !e.within(popover.el))
       popover.hide();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
  hidePopOverIfClickOutside(ev);
});
```

Comment: Can't make it to work. The code from Molecule Man is ok. JQuery popover plugin is done in similar way. With blur event looks cleaner to me. Can you explain to which element to advice the blur event.

Answer (score 1):

The [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event is sent to an element when it loses focus.